# rails, user signing out after editing profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, helper

I was wondering why a user keeps getting signed out after editing their profile? my update function is

```
  def update
    flash[:notice] = "what is params[id]", params[:id]
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      #flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

the `params id` is getting passed correctly, and everything updates correctly on my db. my form in `users/edit.html.erb` is

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %> 
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">

      <%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
      <%= render 'fields', object: f.object, f: f %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :style =>"display:block;" %>

      <%= image_tag(@user.image_url(:thumb), :class => "image_avatar") if @user.image? %>

      <%= f.file_field :image, :class=>"upload_button" %>
      <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the `devise gem`, but this edit is not using the devise route (I'm using devise for registration). could that be affecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, devise has a [sign_in](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#sign_in-instance_method) method.

However, your users shouldn't be signed out after editing their profile.

Comment: oh wow thank you for the rubydoc site! i never knew about it! hmmm for some reason, even after adding in sign_in @user, my users still get signed out. could you think of any reasons why this might be?

Comment: Is the above controller code complete? What's passed as params[:user] (show your form)?

Comment: i edited the question instead of pasting everything in the comments

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this weird problem too and in my case it was due to the password being regenerated when the user was saved. This happened eventhough the password field was not present in the profile form. The reset was happening via an ActiveRecord callback that assigned users with facebook authentication a random password. I fixed it by making sure I never assign a random password to users who already have an encrypted_password set.

Devise stores users in the session via the warden gem and what gets stored looks something like [[user_id], encrypted_password] (in session['warden.user.user.key']). When the password was changed wardens user lookup in the session would fail - since the encrypted password no longer matched - and thus the user would be logged out.