# User signed out on Heroku after editing profile - using signin from Hartl railstutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, heroku, railstutorial.org, dev-to-production

My problem is similar to [rails, user signing out after editing profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132612/rails-user-signing-out-after-editing)
But I am not using devise for signin/signup, rather I'm using the code as copied from Michael Hartl's railstutorial chapters 7-9. And it works great in development! But once I push to Heroku, my app signs users out after they save edits (updates) to their profile. The edits are saved to the database correctly.

Here's github: https://github.com/crowdpublishtv/crowdpublishtv

Here's my users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @books = @user.books
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  def blog
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # blog.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  def profileinfo
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # profileinfo.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  def booklist
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @books = @user.books
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # booklist.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @books = @user.books
    @book = current_user.books.build if signed_in?
    @booklist = Book.where(:user_id => @user.id)
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @booklist = Book.where(:user_id => @user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'profileinfo'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." 
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(signin_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

Comment: Added users_controller.rb & provided Github link. But since it's fine on my localhost, I would think it's not so much an issue with the controller or update method as some kind of difference between development & production (I still have default config/environments/development.rb & config/environments/production.rb) or some kind of Heroku cookie-saving/deleting issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the Devise gem and this problem went away